# How to fix a Visual Studio build error: [MSB3248: Parameter "SearchPaths" has invalid value]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017

My previous Work PC had Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2013 Pro. Using that instance of Visual Studio, I have developed several C# asp.net mvc projects (mostly between 4.5 and 4.5.2 framework versions). However, my system has been replaced with a Windows 10 & Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition and all of my previous projects now have a build error with the following message:

```
Parameter "SearchPaths" has invalid value "C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies, Inc.\LEADTOOLS\Redist\DOTNET\
```

I have tried the following:

- Deleted .vs, .suo, bin, release
- Clean and Rebuild
- Repair Visual Studio 2017 installation
- Another system with the same configuration

The only workaround I have found so far is to create a new project using vs2017 and re-add the files. Can someone explain why am I getting this error and any possible solutions that I should look into, instead of re-doing my projects all over.

**UPDATE / SOLVED**
I found out that some of my projects uses SharePoint 2013 Client and it needs to be installed from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585 and a Nuget Package install does not cut it out.

Comment: How about comparing the recreated project file with the original? You may be able to see where the problem is and fix it by editing the project files (if you don't use source control then make sure you backup the project files before editing them, as they are easy to break)

Comment: I managed to get one project to work by editing csproj file and changing the MSBuild version, but it did not work with other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that some of my projects uses SharePoint 2013 Client and it needs to be installed from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585 and a Nuget Package install does not cut it out.

Answer (score 0):

use path `\\` instead of `\`. For example:

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LEAD Technologies, Inc.\\LEADTOOLS\\Redist\\DOTNET\\
```

Comment: The problem is, I am not even referring to this folder. It just appears in the error  message and I have no idea why.

Comment: [check](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5c18a1e1-bb81-4d99-8267-bf0d14092085/vs2010-builds-my-project-but-msbuild-doesnt-build-my-project?forum=msbuild) this link. Hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by removing the period (.) from the path. I changed the registry setting value HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\LEADTOOLS For .NET

from
C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies, Inc.\LEADTOOLS\Redist\DOTNET
to
C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies, Inc\LEADTOOLS\Redist\DOTNET\